# 23,000 sticks & 500 balls

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve two questions that relate to self study. I phrased the questions in a way that makes sense to me, so please ask for clarification if my questions are unclear.

Situation:

- 23,000 sticks
- 500 balls
- first stick is named A, second stick B, etc…

Questions:

1. Each stick can have 500 balls associated with it. So stick A has 500 balls, stick B has 500 balls, and so on. I think this is represented as: 23,000 sticks x 500 balls per stick = 11,500,000 balls. How is that represented as an exponent?
2. This question does not relate to #1. Suppose we combine stick A and B into a stick called AB. Stick AB can have 500 balls associated with it, Stick BC can also have 500 balls associated with it, the same for Stick CD, and so on. Stick BA does not count since Stick AB is identical, same for CB, and so on. How is that expressed mathematically?
3. What is the proper name for this area of mathematics?

It is times like this that I wish I would have been taught mathematics instead of being taught how to memorize mathematics. Live and learn, I guess. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: The area of mathematics that studies counting is called combinatorics.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions are not clear.  For 1, if you just choose one stick and one ball and associate them, you are correct.  There is no exponent because there is only one item of interest.  In a sense it is $(23000 \cdot 500)^1.$  But it sounds like you might associate a ball with each stick, allowing the balls to be reused.  In that case you have $23000^{500}$ assignments, which is enormous.

For 2, There are $n$ choices for the first stick and $n-1$ for the second stick between each pair, there are now $\frac 12n(n-1)$ pairs of sticks, where the division by $2$ accounts for the fact that we don't care about the order.  This would be represented as $n \choose 2$, the number of unordered combinations of two out of $n$ objects.

Comment: Ross, thank you for your quick reply. I rephrased my questions in an effort to be clearer.

Comment: See if I have addressed what you are interested in